# How does touch / gesture support in WPF compare with Windows Store API

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have been looking but have been unable to find as yet a nice comparison of the differences in touch / gesture support between the Windows Store app API's and WPF.

I have seen that WPF includes some basic touch events but do the WPF controls handle gestures such as swipe, hold and tap or would we need to implement our own identification of these getsures using the basic touch events?

Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full list of Windows Store App controls:
[wpf controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465351.aspx)

When developing a Windows Store App, you will use there controls. They have (where applicable) built in gesture support.

Comment: This does not answer the question about WPF touch and gesture support.